# Values change in applet unexpectedly

Tags: java, applet

Why do values of variables change every time i open a page with applet?

I override paint method:

```
private int osY=14;

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g.drawLine(50,100,50,360);
    for(int j=100;j<=360; j=j+20)
    {
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2.drawLine(50,j,60,j);
        g2.drawString(String.valueOf(osY), 5, j+3);
        g2.setStroke (new BasicStroke(2, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{1}, 0));
        if(j<360) g2.drawLine(60,j,410,j);
        osY--;
    }
}
```

I want to add a label for every vertical hatch mark from 14 to 0. But instead of going downward from 14 (14,13,12,..) it goes from -14 (-14,-15,..).

The second problem more important for me is like in topic unexpected change of this values every time I open this website. So when I first time open applet it goes -14,..-27 but every next time it goes less and less (-28,..-41) and so on.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the scope of the variable. You the keyword this.

```
g2.drawString(String.valueOf(this.osY), 5, j+3);

this.osY--;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not change anything.